# non transparent favicon for Stack Exchange Data Explorer

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, logo, favicon

I just noticed that the favicon for [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com/) is not transparent.

I don't think it was intentional as all other favicons on the SO sister sites are actually transparent.

Shot of my Chrome Bookmarks Bar:

[image]

Comment: I read this as meaning you wanted one!

Comment: @ChrisF: I don't *want* one as such, just pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it:

[image]

Please use http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/ to convert it to a *real* favicon. I can do it as good myself, but no one free image hosting swallows `.ico` files, so you'll have to grab the above `.png` and convert yourself ;)